# Grub2 grub-mkconfig missing

Tags: grub2

I installed grub2 for windows. But I cannot find grub-mkconfig.exe to generate grub.cfg file.I tried grub-install directory to find it.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042853/install-grub2-in-windows-specific-partition

Comment: W I am trying to say is that the installation is successful. But I can't find grub-mkconfig.exe to generate grub.cfg